# How to put contrasting information into a CGridView column based on a condition?

Tags: yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I'm looking into showing/hiding specific column data on a `CGridView` widget for the Wii Framework.

I have a `CButtonColumn` which contains 3 buttons.  However, on certain conditions, I want to display something different for a particular row.
I have 3 different conditions which determin what gets displayed for particular row.

The following illustrates what I want to do:

```
| 1 | Title A | [hide][view][update]            <-- if (condition == 'a')
| 2 | Title B | [hide][view][update]            <-- if (condition == 'a')
| 3 | Title C | display text or link or button  <-- if (condition == 'b')
| 4 | Title D | display alternative buttons     <-- if (condition == 'c')
```

What is my best approach to take here?

I can't use `'visible'=> $model->processingStatus != "processed"` on the column because this will remove the whole column.  I need to target each row insatead.

Should I use the `'visible'` parameter on each individual button?  I have tried this using the commented out code below but it breaks the page.
FYI: I have successfully tried the 'visible' parameter on the CButtonColumn itself, but its not what I need.  Plus not sure which row's status it is reading.

Or should I add a function to the controller?  Have it do the if/else statements and return back what is to be displayed.  How would this work?

Here is my code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'my-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(

        array(
            'name'=>'myid',
            'header'=>'ID',
            ),

        'Title',

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'visible'=> $model->status != "done",
            'template'=>'{hide}{view}{update}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'hide'=>array(
                    'label'=>'Hide',                                                    //Text label of the button.
                    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/img/icons/bulb-off.png'    //Image URL of the button.
                    //'click'=>'function(){alert("Toggle Hide!");}',                    //A JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked.
                    //'options'=>array(),               //HTML options for the button tag.
                    //'url'=>'javascript:void(0)',              //A PHP expression for generating the URL of the button.
                    //'visible'=> $model->status == "done",     //A PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible.
                ),
                'view'=>array(
                    //Text label of the button.
                    'label'=>'View',
                    //Image URL of the button.
                    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/img/icons/view-record.png'
                ),
                'update'=>array(
                    'label'=>'Update/Edit',
                    'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/img/icons/edit-pencil.png',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("metadataandchapters/create?bookid=" . $data->bookid)',
                )
            )
        )
    )
)); ?>
```

Hope I am making good enough sense here!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `visible` button option, but it should be a PHP expression string, e.g. :

```
'visible'=> '$data->status == "done"',
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

Answer (score 0):

Extend CButtonColumn with your own class, then you should be able to change this function to whatever you need to render or hide buttons or do any changes you want.

```
/**
 * Renders a link button.
 * @param string $id the ID of the button
 * @param array $button the button configuration which may contain 'label', 'url', 'data-icon', 'imageUrl' and 'options' elements.
 * @param integer $row the row number (zero-based)
 * @param mixed $data the data object associated with the row
 */
protected function renderButton($id, $button, $row, $data)
```

More details about the function http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#renderButton-detail